# How to integrate Google Plus OAuth API with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-oauth

I'm trying to build a simple project in which the google plus profile data will be saved or will  get updated into the database. I'm unable to figure the way out of invalid character URI problem. I'm getting invalid character URI as response from google.

How can I solve this problem of invalid URI?

I have attached the image of the error at the end of this post.

**Login Controller class code is:**

```
 public function index() {


      // Include the google api php libraries
    include_once APPPATH."libraries/google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php";
    include_once APPPATH."libraries/google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

    // Google Project API Credentials
    $clientId = 'My Client ID';
    $clientSecret = 'My Secret here';
    $redirectUrl = 'https://example.com/index.php?login/index/';

    // Google Client Configuration
    $gClient = new Google_Client();
    $gClient->setApplicationName('Login to Application');
    $gClient->setClientId($clientId);
    $gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
    $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectUrl);
    $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

    if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        $gClient->authenticate();
        $this->session->set_userdata('token', $gClient->getAccessToken());
        redirect($redirectUrl);
    }

    $token = $this->session->userdata('token');
    if (!empty($token)) {
        $gClient->setAccessToken($token);
    }

    if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
        $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
        // Preparing data for database insertion
        $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'google';
        $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
        $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['given_name'];
        $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['family_name'];
        $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
        $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
        $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
        $userData['profile_url'] = $userProfile['link'];     
        $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture'];
        // Insert or update user data
        $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
        if(!empty($userID)){
            $data['userData'] = $userData;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
        } else {
           $data['userData'] = array();
        }
    } else {
        $data['authUrl'] = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    }
    $this->load->view('backend/login',$data);
}
```

The **image of the  error** : 
[image]

I am unable to tackle the problem. Please suggest me how can I avoid this.

Comment: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-google-oauth-php/ might be helpful.

Comment: You can use route for this. Set route in config folder